# Returning all ATM where id of update is not matching current update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one with ATM ids and one where are requests for updates from ATM.

I want to select all ATM ids which don't have update request for updateId in (115,116,117)

I've been thinking about something like this

`SELECT ATMId from tableWithUpdates where ATMUpdateApplicationId not in(115)` but, it will return atm with id 28, even tho it has update request for UpdateApplicationId = 115, and I have no idea why. Any help?

Tables look like this:

Table 1:

> int autoincrement ATMId, VARCHAR(200) ATMName,

Table ATMUpdatesRequest:

> int autoincrement id, DateTime created, int ATMUpdateApplicationId,
>   int ATMId

The point is to find every ATMId that has not a request for ATMUpdateApplicationId in range of 115-117.

### Added from Comment:

Since that ATMId will have other updates, i will still return it, even tho it does not have update with id = 115.I need to not return that ATMId at all if it has any of those 3 numbers.

Link for SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e995

Comment: You really need to post at the names and columns from your 2 tables if you want to get meaningful help from us.

Comment: Please share your table structure with some sample data and expected out put. In the current form, the question is pretty vague

Comment: Updated with SQLFiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below query to avoid ATMUpdateApplicationId in that range

```
   SELECT ATMId from tableWithUpdates where ATMUpdateApplicationId not in(115,116,117)
```

Or

```
 SELECT ATMId from tableWithUpdates where ATMUpdateApplicationId NOT BETWEEN 115 AND 117
```

**Update**

If you want to select ID's other than ATMid belongs to 115,116 or 117 then here is how you can do it

```
SELECT ATMID FROM ATMUpdatesRequest
WHERE ATMID NOT IN(
SELECT ATMID from ATMUpdatesRequest 
WHERE ATMUpdateApplicationId NOT IN(115,116,117))
```

Comment: Thanks for post, but this really not solves my problem. Since that ATMId will have other updates, i will still return it, even tho it does not have update with id = 115.I need to not return that ATMId at all if it has any of those 3 numbers.

Comment: So you mean you want every ATMid except the one which belongs to 115,116 or 117 ? If that you mean then check update in my answer